# sort a list of objects by date in angular

Tags: angular, sorting, date, http, components

i want to sort by date the array of `posts`, but first i want to see if there are objects in `posts`, the list of posts is showed correctly in the html but in `console.log` it looks `undefined`. can you help me?

posts.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { PostsService} from '../posts.service';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeIt from '@angular/common/locales/it';

registerLocaleData(localeIt, 'it');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private loginservice: LoginService,
              private location: Location,
              private postsservice: PostsService) {}
  posts: Post[];
  postDetail(id: number){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts();
    console.log(this.posts);
  }

 getPosts(): void {

   this.postsservice.getPosts()
   .subscribe(posts=>this.posts=posts);

 }


}
```

post.component.html

```
<div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
    <p>written by {{ post.author }}  {{ post.date | date:'medium':'':''}}
      <a class="details" routerLink="/detail/{{post.id}}">></a>
    </p>
    <br>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

posts.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from './post';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {

  private postsUrl = 'api/posts';  // URL to web api
  posts = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /** GET posts from the server */
  getPosts (): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postsUrl)
  }

  getPost(id: number): Observable<Post> {
    const url = `${this.postsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Post>(url);
  }

  /** PUT: update the post on the server */
  updatePost (post: Post): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.postsUrl, post, httpOptions);
  }

  /** POST: add a new post to the server */
  addPost (post: Post): Observable<Post> {
    return this.http.post<Post>(this.postsUrl, post, httpOptions);
  }
  /** DELETE: delete the post from the server */
  deletePost (post: Post | number): Observable<Post> {
    const id = typeof post === 'number' ? post : post.id;
    const url = `${this.postsUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http.delete<Post>(url, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: getPosts is asynchronous. You will need to move your console.log statement inside the subscribe function: `.subscribe(posts=>{ this.posts=posts; console.log(this.posts)});`

Comment: and if i want to sort by date the posts where i can do that?

Comment: Also in the subscribe function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that there are posts you can use a filter. That way you don't need any logic for this when you subscribe to the observable eg.

```
getPosts (): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postsUrl)
           .pipe(filter(posts => posts && posts.length > 0));
}
```

Rather than sorting the posts in the subscribe of the component I would be inclined to keep the logic in the service and use a map for this, eg.

```
getPosts (): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postsUrl)
           .pipe(
                filter(posts => posts && posts.length > 0),
                map(posts => sortBy(posts, ['date'])
            );
}
```

In the above example I have just used the lodash sortBy syntax, but you can use what ever method you want in the map to return the sorted array. If you have a need elsewhere for unsorted posts you can either have a separate getSortedPosts method, or pass a parameter to getPosts(sortBy).

Comment: does filter and map come OOTB with Angular (7, in my case) or is there some way I need to import it? I am not getting it recognized in my IDE

Comment: You need to import each of the rxjs operators, eg.
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';